# Javac can't be recognized

Tags: java, windows, system, javac

As the two pictures show below, I've changed the variables in system.
But don't know why it still doesn't work for java...

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have added the Java path to the User variable but you need to add it to the System variable (You can see a variable named Path is already there, you just need to append your java path).

Comment: have you set up your environment variables path?
i'd suggest going through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/windows_jdk_install.html

Comment: You have added the path to the jre, but you need the one to the jdk

Comment: Seems you missed jdk path. You can set a `JAVA_HOME`, then let jre path and jdk path both direct to `JAVA_HOME`.  http://www.runoob.com/java/java-environment-setup.html

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME is not mandatory to run a java program. However, it is recommended to set it. Setting path to "/jdk/bin "  you just telling the system where javac , java, javap etc located

Answer (score 0):

It's a common mistake : you've installed a JRE when you need a JDK.

Comment: thanks a lot for! got JDK and JRE info.. it's solved!